# Laravel 5 download excel file (maatwebsite/excel) under storage/export through AJAX

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to download an excel file which stored into storage/export/ path. I used Maatwebsite excel provider for this in laravel 5.5.

My controller code is written below:

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
Excel::create($excelName, function($excel) use($adminUserDataExcelSelected) {
$excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($adminUserDataExcelSelected) {
$sheet->fromArray($adminUserDataExcelSelected);
});
})->store('xlsx');
ob_flush();
return response()->json(['path' => $path]);
```

My AJAX code is following;

```
$.ajax({
url: "/administrator/adminUser/exportselected/1/",
type:'POST',
data: {_token:_token, selected:selected, selectedField:selectedField},
success: function(data) { alert(data.path);
if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
}else{}
}
});
```

When I alert/ console.log the data.path, I received the below :

> /var/www/html/stmd_OLD/storage/export/Admin-Users2018-05-17 04:46:47

My question is: How can instantly download the excel file now? Should I call another AJAX method here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace this line `return response()->json(['path' => $path]);`
with this line

```
return response()->download(storage_path('storage/export/AdminUsers2018-05-17 04:46:47.xlsx'));
```

Then you just need to hit the link that calls the controller function that returns this. No need for extra AJAX call.

You may need to add this line at the start of the controller too

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

Comment: I modified the code However, the excel file is not downloading. Should I change the AJAX code too ?

Comment: Can you see the file in your storage/export folder? Normally downloadable files are kept under public folder because it has all the permissions. Try downloading the file from public folder.

Comment: Why is your Ajax call in POST format. the route should be GET

Comment: I have used POST method in ajax because I have to give the inputs to generate the excel file first.

Comment: What will be the code to download the file from public folder instead of storage?

Comment: The code is same you just have to change the directory like this return response()->download(storage_path('app/public/export/AdminUsers2018-05-17 04:46:47.xlsx'));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171198/discussion-between-sakib-abrar-and-niladri-banerjee-uttarpara).